# Is swscanf substring formatting ([a-z]) implemented for osx standard lib?

Tags: c++, macos

The following code works on windows, but not on osx.

The docs on swscanf say that:

> "...some implementations of wscanf() use "A-Z" to represent the range of characters between 'A' and 'Z'. "

By some implementations, does it mean that osx doesn't implement it?

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    {
        wchar_t foo[] = L"bif3.zip";
        wchar_t buh[10] = L"";
        int val = 0;
        wchar_t ext[4] = L"";

        int s = swscanf(foo, L"%[a-z]%d.%ls", buh, &val, ext);
        wprintf(L"wchar: %ls %d %ls\n", buh, val, ext);
    }

    {
        char foo[] = "bif3.zip";
        char buh[10] = "";
        int val = 0;
        char ext[4] = "";

        int s = sscanf(foo, "%[a-z]%d.%s", buh, &val, ext);
        printf("char: %s %d %s\n", buh, val, ext);
    }
}
```

result:

```
wchar:  0
char: bif 3 zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [man page for swscanf(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/swscanf.3.html) states the following under the Bugs section:

> In addition to the bugs documented in scanf(3), wscanf() does not support the “A-Z” notation for specifying character ranges with the character class conversion (‘%[’).

Feel free to [file a bug report with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Lesson: Read the bugs section more carefully.
I ended up using wistringstream and isdigit() for doing my filename break up.